# Python function call on player input

Tags: python, function, call

I have a problem in python with pygame. I want to "jump to" a function after a specific input is made by the user (In this case when up arrow key is pressed down), and then while in that function (start1) i call back to main() again and when "up arrow key" is pressed again i want to get into start()

When i run the program i get this:

RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

Any advice?

Here is the code:

```
def main(text, func):

    exit = False
    while not exit:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                func

            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

    screen.fill(black)

    text = str(text)
    font = pygame.font.SysFont('georgia', 16)
    message = font.render(text, True, white)
    screen.blit(message, (screen_width / 2, screen_height / 2))

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(30)



def start():
    main("Hello, press key-up to get to start 1!", start1())


def start1():
    os.system('cls')
    main("Good, Back to start on Key-up", start())



start()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're not passing `start1` and `start` functions to `main` but you *call* them instead *before* main is even called.

```
def start():
    main("Hello, press key-up to get to start 1!", start1())

def start1():
    os.system('cls')
    main("Good, Back to start on Key-up", start())
```

`start` calls `start1`, which calls `start` when evaluating the parameters of `main` in each routine. `main` hasn't a chance to be called: infinite ping-pong recursion occurs first.

change to:

```
def start():
    main("Hello, press key-up to get to start 1!", start1)

def start1():
    os.system('cls')
    main("Good, Back to start on Key-up", start)
```

and in `main` replace `func` by `func()` in the code like this to *call* your function here:

```
if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
    func()
```

Comment: Oh nice little help there!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of thinking in terms of jumps, try to think in terms of states. State machines is a very typical tool of game development.

You have (at least) 3 states: "up not pressed", "up pressed once", "up pressed twice in a row".

Store this state in a variable, update it on keypresses. Then when <kbd>Up</kbd> is pressed, you can readily know if you want to invoke `start()` or not.